# 2015 visual studio Nuget package manager does not let me save new package sources and Nuget.Config is not valid XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package

2015 visual studio Nuget package manager does not let me save new package sources. 
I did the following:

1. In Visual Studio, navigate to Tools-->Options-->NuGet Package Manager
2. Package Sources and then, press + to add the packages. Everything worked appropriately but, the sources are not saved
3. When, i restart, I see the following on the start of visual studio

   Nuget operation failed

   Nuget.Config is not valid XML. Path:
   'C:\Users\mnperezp\AppData\Roaming\Nuget\Nuget.Config'. '.',
   hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

I tried the following:

1. Look for the location of this config file. 
   I do not have anything called like that. 
   The closer that i see is the following: C:\Users\mnperezp.nuget\packages
2. Uninstall and install the Nuget package manager--> I observed the same
3. Update the Powershell ISE 5.0--> I observed the same.

Could you give me some tips on how to proceed? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `NuGet.Config` from:

```
C:\Users\your-username\AppData\Roaming\NuGet
```

Upon re-opening **VS2015** a new config file will be created and the issue should be resolved.

Comment: I already tried this since i saw that in a previous answer. I actually do not have a folder with this. The only folder that i see is the following: C:\Users\mnperezp\.nuget\packages

Comment: %AppData% in file explorer?